# Flutter app rejected due to 3.1.1 - Business - Payments -In-App Purchase from App store

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I received a message from Apple, but I don't understand the issue mentioned. How can I resolve this problem?

I am using `Stripe` method for payment.

> **Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase**
>
> We noticed that your app includes or accesses paid digital content,
> services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which
> is not appropriate for the App Store. Specifically:
>
> - The subscriptions can be purchased in the app using payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase.
>
> Next Steps
>
> The paid digital content, services, or subscriptions included in or
> accessed by your app must be available for purchase using in-app
> purchase.
>
> If you have any additional information to provide regarding the
> digital content and services in your app and how the guidelines apply
> to them, please reply to this message in App Store Connect and let us
> know. If there is information you'd like us to consider in our review
> of future submissions, please feel free to include it in the App
> Review Information section of App Store Connect.

Rejection attachments:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apple doesn't allow other payment method than their in-app purchase. You need to remove Stripe and have it on your website, for example, but it can't be in the app.

Comment: so, should I use in-app purchase rather than stripe in iOS app? As on android I have implemented stripe and it has been successfully uploaded on play store.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Flutter.

Apple have strict policy for selling digital content. You can not do it through card or any other payment methods. You can only do it by in-app purchase.

> The paid digital content, services, or subscriptions included in or
> accessed by your app must be available for purchase using in-app
> purchase.

Stripe can be used to sell physical goods.

Comment: I have successfully uploaded my app on `google play store` but on `app store` they have rejected my app. So now kindly tell me how can i use it in only for ios

Comment: Google Play Store own by Google which allowed you. App Store own by apple and have strict policy, so it don't allow this.